# Python directory on github cron not found

Tags: python, github-actions

I created a cronjob with value contents like this:
**cronjob.yml**

```
name: Cron

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/30 * * * *"

jobs:
  auto_predict:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
      
    env:
      REGISTRY: "registry.digitalocean.com/xxx"
      IMAGE_NAME: "xxx-xxx"
      
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repo 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install doctl
        uses: xxx/action-doctl@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.XXX_TOKEN }}
    
      - name: Log in to Container Registry with short-lived credentials
        run: doctl registry login --expiry-seconds 600

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential python3.11-venv
          python3.11 -m venv env
          source env/bin/activate
          sudo pip install exceptiongroup
          sudo pip install poetry
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE 
          sudo poetry config virtualenvs.create false && sudo poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi
          
      - name: Run the cron job
        run: |
           cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
           python app/services/auto_predict_service.py
```

then the value of **auto_predict_service.py**

```
from fastapi import HTTPException, Depends
from app.utils.api_utils import validate_api_key
from joblib import load
import psycopg2
from app.db.connection import postgreSQL_connection

# Load classifier model
classifier_model_path = "./app/models/best_nb_classifier.joblib"
classifier_model = load(classifier_model_path)

# Load TF-IDF vectorizer
vectorizer_path = "./app/models/tfidf_vectorizer.joblib"
vectorizer = load(vectorizer_path)

def predict_genre(api_key: str = Depends(validate_api_key)):
    cursor = None

    try:
        cursor = postgreSQL_connection.get_cursor()
        
        # Select and lock the first 3 rows with NULL Genre
        query = """SELECT "ISBN", "Book-Title", "Book-Author", "Publisher", "Year-Of-Publication", "Image-URL-S", "Image-URL-M", "User-ID", "Book-Rating", "Age"
                   FROM books
                   WHERE "Genre" IS NULL
                   ORDER BY "ISBN"
                   FOR UPDATE
                   LIMIT 3;"""
        cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        
        # Predict genre for each data
        predictions = []
        for row in data:
            book_title = row[1]
            title_features = vectorizer.transform([book_title])
            input_features = title_features
            predicted_genre = classifier_model.predict(input_features)[0]
            predictions.append({
                "ISBN": row[0],
                "Book_Title": book_title,
                "Book_Author": row[2],
                "Publisher": row[3],
                "Year_Of_Publication": row[4],
                "Image_URL_S": row[5],
                "Image_URL_M": row[6],
                "User_ID": row[7],
                "Book_Rating": row[8],
                "Age": row[9],
                "Predicted_Genre": predicted_genre
            })
        
        # Update the first 3 rows with predicted Genre
        for pred in predictions:
            update_query = """UPDATE books
                              SET "Genre" = %s
                              WHERE "ISBN" = %s;"""
            update_data = (pred["Predicted_Genre"], pred["ISBN"])
            cursor.execute(update_query, update_data)
            postgreSQL_connection.connection.commit()

        cursor.close()

        response = {
            "status": "Success",
            "res_status": 200,
            "data": predictions
        }
        return response

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

# Run function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    predict_genre()
```

when running the .yml for the conjob there was an error
*from app.utils.api_utils import validate_api_key
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'*

Meaning the directory was not found, is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: `python app/services/auto_predict_service.py` When you run a script like this, the default module search path will be `app/services`.  It can't find `app` because you're _already_ inside of that folder.

Comment: thanks, so what should it be?

Comment: The easiest solution might be to set a PYTHONPATH environment variable, with the value of $GITHUB_WORKSPACE.